# What's the difference between Watson's android-sdk and java-sdk packages?

Tags: ibm-watson

Which package should we use for creating Android apps that work with Watson services?

Do we use Watson's [android-sdk](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/android-sdk) package or its [java-sdk](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk) package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Watson Android SDK is just a companion to Java SDK. It is intended to be used **with** Java SDK and augments it with some Android-specific functionality helpers, for example

- Audio/Microphone
- Camera
- Gallery

In fact, if you look at the example in Android SDK it has the dependency on Java SDK and there is no much in the Android SDK sources except few helpers.

So the answer is you either use Java SDK (if you don't need Android extra functionality) or both.